# How to replace using regular expression in nested string?

Tags: java, regex

I have this:
`start_xxx_end_Leftstart_xxx_end_Right`

How can I use the regular expression to remove characters between `start` and `end` (inclusive) so that I can get the following string:

`_Left_Right`

I tried this regex in java but it removes EVERYTHING between `start` and `end`:

`start(.*)end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `replaceAll` method to replace the substring from `start` to `end`: -

```
String str = "start_xxx_end_Leftstart_xxx_end_Right";
str = str.replaceAll("start.*?end", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
"_Left_Right"
```